# How to create an ISAPI Filter in VS 2005/2008

Tags: visual-c++, iis, iis-6, isapi, isapi-extension

In VS 6.0 we had a option for selecting a project type as MFC ISAPI Extension Dll under VC++ and then configuring it as a Filter object. 
How do we achieve this in VS 2005/2008?

Answer (score 0):

The [ISAPI project template is removed in 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/03/25/mfc-isapi-template-and-isapi-development.aspx) and class library support is removed in 2008.

You can create the project in VC6 then upgrade the project to 2005, but this method won't work in 2008 unless [you copy the 2005 ISAPI MFC files to 2008.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2007/12/10/chttpserver-not-included-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx)

Note [ISAPI filter is being deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831460.aspx). IIS7 has ISAPI Filter support but not as a default install option.